# When is $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $x\in\mathbb{C}$, and consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(x)$. If this field is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, then $x$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, so satisfies some polynomial $P$. Any field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ will send $x$ to a root of $P$, so $x$ has a finite orbit under $Aut(\mathbb{C})$.

How do I prove the converse? That is, if $x$ has a finite orbit under $Aut(\mathbb{C})$, how do we know that $\mathbb{Q}(x)/\mathbb{Q}$ is finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1, \dots, x_n$ be the orbit of $x$. Then $p(t)=\Pi_{i=1}^n (t-x_i)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$ since it is fixed by all automomorpishms of $\mathbb C$. But then $x$ is algebraic because $p(x)=0$.

Comment: Very good, I would have said the same, so ***+1***.  But how do we know that *precisely*  $\Bbb Q$ is fixed by all $\alpha  \in Aut(\Bbb C)$?

Comment: @RobertLewis, if $\alpha$ is fixed by all automomorpishms  then it is real because it is fixed by complex conjugation. Now the only field automomorpishm of the reals is the identity. Does that work?

Comment: @RobertLewis Use Zorn's lemma to construct transcendence bases of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, and then use Zorn's lemma again to construct the appropriate automorphisms by extending automorphisms of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: Of course! Good answer.

Comment: @Zhen Lin:  $\bar{\Bbb Q}$ is the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$, right?